# replace a fragment without onDestroy

Tags: android, memory-leaks, fragment

In my android app I have fragments, and one of them is very heavy (it loads many things from the web), and other one is light (like settings panel).

I switch between fragments with something like this :

```
private Fragment myFragment1;
private Fragment myFragment2;
......
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, myFragment2);
ft.commit();
```

My problem is that it goes in onStop() and onDestroy() of the fragment when it's beeing replaced.
And because I don't free my heavy stuffs in onDestroy() I got a big memory leak...

**I would like to keep in memory all my fragments**, and only show/hide them from the screen.
This would be good to do a fast switch beteen the screens, without loading everything everytime.

So, the question is :
**How can I change my code to keep all my fragments in memory ?**
I would like to have sonething like :

```
Fragment1.onPause();
Fragment2.onResume();
```

And not :

```
Fragment1.onPause();
Fragment1.onStop();
Fragment1.onDestroy();
Fragment2.onCreate();
Fragment2.onResume();
```

One more thing, I use android.support.v4.app.Fragment on android 2.2 and more.

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT 1:**

I found some help and I did this function :

```
private void changeFragement(Fragment f, String fragmentTag) {
    try {
        if (f != null && fragmentTag != null) {

            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
            if (currentFragment != null)
                ft.hide(currentFragment);

            Fragment cachedFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
            if (cachedFragment == null)
                ft.add(R.id.main_fragment, f, fragmentTag);
            else
                ft.show(f);              

            /*Fragment cachedFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
            if (cachedFragment == null)
                cachedFragment = f;
            ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, cachedFragment, fragmentTag);*/

            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException err) {
    }
}
```

The problem is that the fragments are not well replaced, I don't understand wel the "ft.addToBackStack(null);"...
Could you help me to correct this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Android handles the lifecycle of activities, services, etc... including Fragments.
You need to re-think you do it.

I know there is something about "background" fragments in the doc. Maybe you could do the loading in that one and share some state with the other fragments you display/hide  ?